# How to get report on how many assertEquals statement passed/failed in junit test

Tags: java, maven, junit, assert, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to trying to test a set of result generated by a service class with some defined `expected` result. The service produce the `actual` result.

The service is feed with values from a json file which contain some values and expected result. The output of `service` is compared with `expected` result using `AssertEquals` and the test is passing only when they are equal.

Is it possible to continue test even if some `AssertEquals` fails and generate a report of how many `AssertEquals` have passed or failed.

I explored `maven surefire` but I am not able to get expected result.

Note: There is only one `@Test` method.Inside this method only I am calling the service with multiple times with different parameters and comparing `expected` & `actual` result

```
@Test
    public void createTest() throws Exception {
        try {
            // some other code to read the file
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            // ruleValidationResourcePath is location of the file
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(ruleValidationResourcePath));
            //looping this json and passing each object values to a service
            for(Object o:array){
                JSONObject rulesValidation = (JSONObject) o;
                String ruleAdExpr = (String) rulesValidation.get("ruleA");
                String _result = (String)rulesValidation.get("result");
                PatObj patObj= new PatObj ();
                patObj.setRule(ruleAdExpr.trim());
                //service is an instance of class which hold props method
                PatObj pat = service.props(patObj);
                if(patObj.getRule() != null){
                    String _machineRule =pat .getMachine_rule().toLowerCase().trim();
                    String expResult = _result.toLowerCase().trim();
                    // here some _machineRule & expResult may be different
                    // currently test is failing if they are not equal
                    // will like to continue test even if they are not equal 
                    // and create report of how many failed/passed

                    Assert.assertEquals(_machineRule,expResult);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The idea behind an Assert is simply either it is fulfilled or not...Apart from that maybe I misunderstand your test wrong but it looks like becoming to complex for a test...Can't you handle that in more smaller steps separately...?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to continue test even if some AssertEquals fails.

Yes, it is possible but I wouldn't recommend you doing that because it is misuse of JUnit.

The JUnit methodology follows the rule that a test should check only one particular case per test method.

In your case you JSON loading logic is just a setup, and you check `getMachineRule()` method with different parameters.

JUnit world has its own mechanisms of handling such cases.

**How do you implement it properly:**

You need to rework the test by making it parametrised.

First add [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) to your project.

Then you need to introduce a method that will load `JSONArray` and use its result as parameters for your test.

All together:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class RoleTest {

    @Test
    @Parameters
    public void createTest(JSONObject rulesValidation) throws Exception {
        // use the same logic as you have inside your "for" loop
        //...
        assertEquals(machineRule, expResult);
    }

    private Object[] parametersForCreateTest() {
        // load JSON here and convert it to array
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parser.parse(
                new FileReader(ruleValidationResourcePath)
        );
        return jsonArray.toArray();
    }
}
```

This way the `createTest` will be performed as many times as you have objects in your `JSONArray` and you'll see the report for each particular run (even if some of them fail).

**Note:** the method naming matters. A method that return parameters should be named the same way as the test method but prefixed with `parametersFor` - in your case `parametersForCreateTest`. Find more examples in [the documentation](https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams/wiki/Quickstart).

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much goes against what the Assertion is intended. One of the difficulties here is that a failed assertion throws an error and not an exception.

You could use:

```
catch (AssertionError e) {
...
```

Once you catch the error, you still need to tally it so the code would be far cleaner if you simply made the comparison using an if statement and recording the result

```
if(_machineRule.equals(expResult)) {success++;}
```

and then

```
Assert.assertEquals(expectedCount,success);
```

after your loop completes processing of all the elements in your list.  Another method might be:

```
try{
      Assert.assertEquals(_machineRule,expResult);
          System.out.println(description + " - passed");

 }catch(AssertionError e){
      System.out.println(description + " - failed");

    throw e;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the *org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector* rule from the junit 4.7+ API.  It should do exactly what you're looking for; allowing a single test to assert multiple times and report the end-state of each check individually.

```
 //This must be public
 @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
    @Test
    public void createTest() throws Exception {
        try {
            // some other code to read the file
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            // ruleValidationResourcePath is location of the file
            JSONArray array = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(ruleValidationResourcePath));
            //looping this json and passing each object values to a service
            for(Object o:array){
                JSONObject rulesValidation = (JSONObject) o;
                String ruleAdExpr = (String) rulesValidation.get("ruleA");
                String _result = (String)rulesValidation.get("result");
                PatObj patObj= new PatObj ();
                patObj.setRule(ruleAdExpr.trim());
                //service is an instance of class which hold props method
                PatObj pat = service.props(patObj);
                if(patObj.getRule() != null){
                    String _machineRule =pat .getMachine_rule().toLowerCase().trim();
                    String expResult = _result.toLowerCase().trim();
                    // here some _machineRule & expResult may be different
                    // currently test is failing if they are not equal
                    // will like to continue test even if they are not equal 
                    // and create report of how many failed/passed

                    collector.checkThat(expResult, IsEqual.equalTo(_machineRule));
                    //Assert.assertEquals(_machineRule,expResult);
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            collector.addError(e);
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```